# How to prefill data in vue form?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vue-component, assign

I am using vue form to edit one item, but I cannot conclude in which method should I assign a values to `categoryName` and `description` to make those values ​​appear in form?

I tried to make axios call and assign response to `categoryName` and `description` in the methods: created, mounted, beforeMouned, but it does not show values of `categoryName` and `description` in input fields, although values are obtained from the backend. Also `v-model.lazy` does not give results.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-5">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitCategory">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categoryName">Category name</label>
        <input v-model.lazy="categoryName" value="categoryName" type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryName" aria-describedby="categoryNameHelp" placeholder="Enter category name">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input v-model="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter description">
      </div>
        <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "EditCategory",
  data() {
    return {
      categoryName: '',
      description: '',
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.$axios.get(`/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`,{
        id: this.$route.params.id
      }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.categoryName = response.categoryName;
      this.description = response.description;
    });    },
  methods: {
    submitCategory() {
      this.$axios.post('/api/categories', {
        categoryName: this.categoryName,
        description: this.description,
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.$router.push({name: 'Categories'});
      })
    },   
    initialize () {
     
     },

  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios Response object

When we send a request to a server, it returns a response. The Axios response object consists of:

1. data - the payload returned from the server
2. status - the HTTP code returned from the server
3. headers - headers sent by server

You did `console.log(response.data)` in BeforeMount Hook. You will get your required data under response.data object

```
this.categoryName = response.data.categoryName;
this.description = response.data.description;
```